# How to handle parent test teardown with parallel subtests in golang

Tags: go

### Overview

If I have a parent test with setup and teardown logic, how do I run subtests within it in parallel without running into a race condition with the teardown logic?

```
func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    // setup logic
    t.Run("a", func(t *testing.T) {
        t.Parallel()
        // test code
    })
    // teardown logic
}
```

### Example

As a contrived example: let's say that the test needs to create a tmp file that will be used by all subtests and delete it when the test is over.

For the example, the parent test also calls `t.Parallel()`, as that's what I ultimately want. But my problem and the output below is the same even if the parent does not call `t.Parallel()`.

#### Sequential Subtest

If I run the subtests sequentially, they pass no problem:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "testing"
)

func setup(t *testing.T) (tmpFile string) {
    f, err := ioutil.TempFile("/tmp", "subtests")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("could not setup tmp file: %+v", err)
    }
    f.Close()
    return f.Name()
}

var ncase = 2

func TestSeqSubtest(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()

    // setup test variables
    fname := setup(t)

    // cleanup test variables
    defer func() {
        os.Remove(fname)
    }()

    for i := 0; i < ncase; i++ {
        t.Run(fmt.Sprintf("test_%d", i), func(t *testing.T) {
            if _, err := os.Stat(fname); os.IsNotExist(err) {
                t.Fatalf("file was removed before subtest finished")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test subtests  
ok      subtests        0.001s
```

#### Parallel Subtest

If, however, I run the subtests in parallel, then the parent test's teardown logic ends up getting called ***before*** the subtest has a chance to run, making it impossible to get the subtest to run correctly.

This behavior, while unfortunate, fits with what the ["Using Subtests and Sub-benchmarks"](https://blog.golang.org/subtests#TOC_7.) go blog says:

> A test is called a parallel test if its test function calls the
>   Parallel method on its instance of testing.T. A parallel test never
>   runs concurrently with a sequential test and its execution is
>   suspended until its calling test function, that of the parent test,
>   has returned.

```
func TestParallelSubtest(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()

    // setup test variables
    fname := setup(t)

    // cleanup test variables
    defer func() {
        os.Remove(fname)
    }()

    for i := 0; i < ncase; i++ {
        t.Run(fmt.Sprintf("test_%d", i), func(t *testing.T) {
            t.Parallel() // the change that breaks things
            if _, err := os.Stat(fname); os.IsNotExist(err) {
                t.Fatalf("file was removed before subtest finished")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test subtests  
--- FAIL: TestParallelSubtest (0.00s)
    --- FAIL: TestParallelSubtest/test_0 (0.00s)
        main_test.go:58: file was removed before subtest finished
    --- FAIL: TestParallelSubtest/test_1 (0.00s)
        main_test.go:58: file was removed before subtest finished
FAIL
FAIL    subtests        0.001s
```

#### Parallel Subtest with WaitGroup

As the above quote states, parallel subtests won't execute until their parent has finished, which means that trying to solve this with a [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) results in a deadlock:

```
func TestWaitGroupParallelSubtest(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // setup test variables
    fname := setup(t)

    // cleanup test variables
    defer func() {
        os.Remove(fname)
    }()

    for i := 0; i < ncase; i++ {
        t.Run(fmt.Sprintf("test_%d", i), func(t *testing.T) {
            wg.Add(1)
            defer wg.Done()
            t.Parallel()
            if _, err := os.Stat(fname); os.IsNotExist(err) {
                t.Fatalf("file was removed before subtest finished")
            }
        })
    }
    wg.Wait() // causes deadlock
}
```

output:

```
$ go test subtests  
--- FAIL: TestParallelSubtest (0.00s)
    --- FAIL: TestParallelSubtest/test_0 (0.00s)
        main_test.go:58: file was removed before subtest finished
    --- FAIL: TestParallelSubtest/test_1 (0.00s)
        main_test.go:58: file was removed before subtest finished
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
testing.tRunner.func1(0xc00009a000)
        /path/to/golang1.1.11/src/testing/testing.go:803 +0x1f3
testing.tRunner(0xc00009a000, 0xc00005fe08)
        /path/to/golang1.1.11/src/testing/testing.go:831 +0xc9
testing.runTests(0xc00000a0a0, 0x6211c0, 0x3, 0x3, 0x40b36f)
        /path/to/golang1.1.11/src/testing/testing.go:1117 +0x2aa
testing.(*M).Run(0xc000096000, 0x0)
        /path/to/golang1.1.11/src/testing/testing.go:1034 +0x165
main.main()
        _testmain.go:46 +0x13d

goroutine 7 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0xc0000a2008)
        /path/to/golang1.1.11/src/runtime/sema.go:56 +0x39
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0xc0000a2000)
        /path/to/golang1.1.11/src/sync/waitgroup.go:130 +0x64
subtests.TestWaitGroupParallelSubtest(0xc00009a300)
        /path/to/go_code/src/subtests/main_test.go:91 +0x2b5
testing.tRunner(0xc00009a300, 0x540f38)
        /path/to/golang1.1.11/src/testing/testing.go:827 +0xbf
created by testing.(*T).Run
        /path/to/golang1.1.11/src/testing/testing.go:878 +0x353

goroutine 8 [chan receive]:
testing.runTests.func1.1(0xc00009a000)
        /path/to/golang1.1.11/src/testing/testing.go:1124 +0x3b
created by testing.runTests.func1
        /path/to/golang1.1.11/src/testing/testing.go:1124 +0xac

goroutine 17 [chan receive]:
testing.(*T).Parallel(0xc0000f6000)
        /path/to/golang1.1.11/src/testing/testing.go:732 +0x1fa
subtests.TestWaitGroupParallelSubtest.func2(0xc0000f6000)
        /path/to/go_code/src/subtests/main_test.go:85 +0x86
testing.tRunner(0xc0000f6000, 0xc0000d6000)
        /path/to/golang1.1.11/src/testing/testing.go:827 +0xbf
created by testing.(*T).Run
        /path/to/golang1.1.11/src/testing/testing.go:878 +0x353

goroutine 18 [chan receive]:
testing.(*T).Parallel(0xc0000f6100)
        /path/to/golang1.1.11/src/testing/testing.go:732 +0x1fa
subtests.TestWaitGroupParallelSubtest.func2(0xc0000f6100)
        /path/to/go_code/src/subtests/main_test.go:85 +0x86
testing.tRunner(0xc0000f6100, 0xc0000d6040)
        /path/to/golang1.1.11/src/testing/testing.go:827 +0xbf
created by testing.(*T).Run
        /path/to/golang1.1.11/src/testing/testing.go:878 +0x353
FAIL    subtests        0.003s
```

### Summary

So how can I go about having a teardown method in the parent test that gets called ***after*** the parallel subtests run?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the [Go Blog on subtests](https://blog.golang.org/subtests) it's mentioned how to do this:

```
func TestParallelSubtest(t *testing.T) {
    // setup test variables
    fname := setup(t)

    t.Run("group", func(t *testing.T) {
        for i := 0; i < ncase; i++ {
            t.Run(fmt.Sprintf("test_%d", i), func(t *testing.T) {
                t.Parallel()
                if _, err := os.Stat(fname); os.IsNotExist(err) {
                    t.Fatalf("file was removed before subtest finished")
                }
            })
        }
    })
    
    os.Remove(fname)
}
```

The relevant part of the blog post is under `Control of Parallelism`:

> Each test is associated with a test function. A test is called a parallel test if its test function calls the Parallel method on its instance of `testing.T`. A parallel test never runs concurrently with a sequential test and its execution is suspended until its calling test function, that of the parent test, has returned. [...]
>
> A test blocks until its test function returns and all of its subtests have completed. This means that the parallel tests that are run by a sequential test will complete before any other consecutive sequential test is run.

The specific solution for your problem can be found in the `Cleaning up after a group of parallel tests` section.

Comment: Shoot my eyes glossed right over the outer `t.Run` call. thanks! (your answer should probably quote the "Cleaning up after a group of parallel tests" section, since the quote you included is the one I also quoted -- and it doesn't explain the solution by itself)

Comment: Yeah the outer `t.Run` call is critical! I tripped over that too.

Answer (score 6):

Since Go 1.14, [`testing.T`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T) and [`testing.B`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#B) have the [`Cleanup`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Cleanup) method that allows to register teardown callbacks.

```golang
t.Cleanup(func() {
    os.Remove(fname)
})
```

Comment: Well, that's incredibly handy. I hadn't noticed they'd added those new methods.